# SAPUI5 deploy application with binary files MIMES

Tags: sapui5

I'm currently building an app with some binary files (jpeg, mp3 ...).
When I upload my app on the gateway system, the binaries are uploaded in a "MIMES" folder.

How can I access those files from SAPUI5 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I placed all my binaries (PNG images in my case) into a separate folder **/png** under **webapp** folder in Web IDE and in controller **onInit** event I calculate the path like this ("*hcm.myleaverequest.ESSLeaveReqExt*" is my app id):

```
this._sPNGpath = $.sap.getModulePath("hcm.myleaverequest.ESSLeaveReqExt", "/png");
```

and also store this path in a local JSON model **ViewSettings** to make it possible use it in binding expressions. Something like this:

```
icon="{ViewSettings>/PNGPath}/mylogo.png"
```

Such an arrangement works fine for me after deploying to the SAP gateway.

**Update for MP3 files:**

It appears Web IDE can't import MP3 file as binary, it always formats it thinking it's a text file. However, if you change the file extension to **png** you can load the file into a project folder. After that you can play the file by standard  tag using sap.ui.core.HTML control:

```
<core:HTML content='&lt;audio controls&gt;&lt;source src="{ViewSettings>/PNGPath}/old_telephone_ringing_copy.png" type="audio/mpeg"&gt;&lt;/audio&gt;'>
```

Most probably it would work after deployment (I didn't try it though)

Comment: OK you're right for PNG. For the MP3, if I do not replace the extension of mp3 to png for example the program refuses to upload the mp3. Do you have a trick ?

Comment: Yeah, I even could not import mp3 into a project folder as Web IDE automatically formats it somehow (why on earth it does this??). I only could import it after changing the extension like you said. However, I managed to play it with standard browser <audio> tag inside sap.ui.core.HTML component, I referenced it with png extension.